# contar numero datos de una fila que cumplan con un carácter

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo una consulta sql en la cual tengo una tabla que tiene como datos D01 hasta D31 como referencia al mes lo que deseo es contar la cantidad de días por registro que tienen como dato "GN" y llenarlo en solo un campo
ejemplo
lo que deseo es que creen un campo que diga guardias nocturnas y coloque el numero de cantidades de veces que se repita

trate con esto pero es algo individual para campo por campo y lo que quiero es evitar realizar tanto codigo

```
SELECT CASE WHEN lower(dbo.programacion_horario.d01) = 'gn3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS GN3, 
       CASE WHEN lower(dbo.programacion_horario.d01) = 'gn2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS GN2
       FROM    dbo.Programacion_Horario
       WHERE   (Mes = '06') AND (Anio = '2018')
```

Comment: Bienvenido l r 3 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Has probado aplicar un `SUM()` sobre cada uno de los `CASE`?

Comment: Lo complicado es que no es solo uno son unas 4 verificaciones que tengo que hacer ,pero bueno igual gracias por tratar de ayudar lo are por la forma mas larga y un poco lenta